# rxdart usage in Flutter not being recognized

Tags: android, dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to use **rxdart** package for the first time in my Flutter app and I have added the package in yaml file, then I saved it and **vscode** automatically ran flutter packages get on project after that complete I tried to import the package with following line

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
```

but the compiler doesn't recognize rxdart within the packages. which is causing the error in the app.

The following are my dependencies of **pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  rxdart: ^0.18.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

### Update

Here is the repo for the project I am working on: https://www.github.com/touseefbsb/LoginStateful

You have to open the folder login_stateful_bloc and the error is in **bloc.dart** file where I am trying to import it.

Comment: do you have any error after execute 'flutter packages get' ?

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: @diegoveloper no I did not get any error after "flutter packages get" I got exit code 0, which I guess means it ran succesfully. error is get is "target of URI doesnt exist  'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart'".

Comment: I cloned your repo and imported 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart' and it is working fine. What is the version of flutter/dart ?

Comment: 0.5.1 flutter and 2.0 dart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to keep the indents :

```
  dependencies:
    flutter:
      sdk: flutter
    cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
    rxdart: ^0.18.0
```

Comment: a few seconds more and I would have said the same. :p

Comment: haha but it's weird because if you don't you use indents you get an error on the console

Comment: sorry the indents in my questions were misleading I have corrected them now. indents are alright in my file and that is why flutter packages get is running fine.

Comment: maybe you could attach a screenshot with the error message and the class where you are using it

Comment: please see the update part of the question. @diegoveloper

Comment: you are using an old version : rxdart: ^0.16.7

Comment: also tried the latest version 0.18.1 still got the same error

Comment: could you add a screenshot , put the mouse over the error line and take screenshot?

Comment: guyx thanks for all the help but I just restarted the IDE and that solved the problem for me strangely. and I accepted the answer because indentation can also cause this problem so it may help somebody else as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Even after pub get, it didn't work. Then I simply restarted my IDE(Android Studio) and now it works.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30445924)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, make sure you putted the dependencies on

```
dependencies:  
   flutter:
```

not

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
```

if that make sense :/